# Clicking outside of an element to hide it, doesn't work with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide multiple navigation bars when clicked outside of it, it makes sense to do so, But only one of them hides for one obvious reason.
HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="navigation-link logo"><b>Aken</b></a></li>
        <li class="right dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="navigation-link nav-trigger">
            Akar Muhamad
            <img  class="profile-picture" src="http://placehold.it/30x30/3498db/333">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true" style="position: relative; right: 3%;"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Profile</a>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="right dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="navigation-link nav-trigger">
            Akar Muhamad
            <img  class="profile-picture" src="http://placehold.it/30x30/3498db/333">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true" style="position: relative; right: 3%;"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Profile</a>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
$('.nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    // Loop through all the drop-downs, and make all of them invisible
    // Except the one we clicked on.
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible');
    var that = this;
    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
        if (that != this) {
            $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
        }
    });
});


// TODO: Fix a bug where it doesn't work on multiple navigation bars.
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target !== $('.nav-trigger')[0]) {
        $('.dropdown').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
        });
    }
});
```

Now, as you can see, I passed `0` as an index to check. But what I want is to loop through all of them and use the index as the key to that. Whenever I do that, it doesn't work at all, It also disables the click to show the navigation content function too.

Here's the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jowelucosi/edit?html,js,console,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the loops and simply hide all of the dropdowns.  Then add back the one you care about if necessary.

This code stores the dropdown visibility at click and uses it to toggle the visibility after hiding the dropdown content. This means that clicking the header will both open and close the dropdown.

```
$('.nav-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    // store current dropdown state
    var visible = $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').hasClass('visible');

    // hide all dropdowns
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');

    // if we were visible, hide, and vice-versa
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible', !visible);

    // prevent document handler from being fired
    event.stopPropagation();
});

// hide all dropdowns if click propagates to document
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
});
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rijediqeve/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't have to use loops here and you don't need to know the `index`.

```
$('.nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    // remove visible class from each .dropdown-content:
    $('.dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
    // add visible class to .dropdown-content next to the clicked .nav-trigger:
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').addClass('visible');
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    // check if the clicked element is .nav-trigger:
    $(event.target).is('.nav-trigger') || 
    // if not, remove visible class from each .dropdown-content:
    $('.dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x3tgtp7L/1/)